# Mi programa debería imprimir el numero introducido pero al imprimirlo solo muestra basura. C

Tags: c

En el programa debo buscar los datos previamente introducidos(nombre,rut y rol)para luego buscar, según el nombre, los datos que fueron introducidos al inicio, pero al hacerlo en vez de imprimir el numero introducido en Rut imprime muchos numeros que no tienen parecido al rut introducido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int i,n,sn=1,datos;
    char nombre[30][30],rol[30][30],BNombre[30];
    int rut[n];
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("Ingrese su primer nombre: ");
        scanf("%s",nombre[i]);
    }for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("Ingrese el rut de %s sin digito verificador: ",nombre[i]);
        scanf("%i",&rut[i]);
    }for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        printf("Ingrese el rol de %s: ",nombre[i]);
        scanf("%s",rol[i]);
    }
    while(sn==1){
        printf("Ingrese el nombre de quien desea buscar: ");
        scanf("%s",BNombre);
        printf("Los datos que va a buscar son de %s\n",BNombre);
        for(i=0;i<1;i++){
            if(strcmp(BNombre,nombre[i])==0){
                datos=i;
                printf("El rut es: %i\n",rut[datos]);
                printf("El rol es: %s\n",rol[datos]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Date cuenta de que `rut` tiene tamaño `n`. Un `n` que esta sin inicializar cuando creas rut

Comment: muhas gracias pablochaches habia estado toda la tarde haciendo eso y no puedo creer que no se me haya ocurrido hacer eso :| muchas gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: Dale, mucha suerte con tu programa. Hay que ponerle los avisos al compilador, asi te enteras en el momento en el que lo pruebas, y te ahorras unas horas de dolor de cabeza